# New Allegiances: Valindor not anywhere to be found?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

Just started the quest, New Allegiances in Skyrim with the Dawnguard DLC, and Vingalmo has told me to turn Valindor into a Vampire. He says that Valindor can be found in Riften, but when I select the quest in the start menu, there is no Quest-marker for the NPC and when I searched all through Riften, there was no sign of him.

I tried looking up a walkthrough for times he'd be wandering around which places, and he never showed. Could this mean Valindor has died somehow? Or is it perhaps a bug? Is there any way I can fix this?

Platform is PS3.

Answer (score 2):

Valindor starts off his day by waking up at 4am and having a long breakfast for two hours in his house. At 6am, he heads off to Riften Fishery and starts working for three hours. At 9am, he goes outside to the docks and works on the fishing boat for three hours until noon. Then, he heads back inside the fishery and works for three hours until 3pm. After that, he goes outside to the boat again and works for another three hours. At 6pm, he finally stops work and proceeds to Haelga's Bunkhouse to consume his dinner and rest for four hours. At 10pm, he returns to his house to sleep for six hours until 4am, and repeats his schedule the following day.
If you own Honeyside, he can be seen occasionally walking through it from the harbor into the city proper.

Note that sometimes Valindor is ridiculously difficult to sneak up on, detecting you even at very high levels of Sneak.

[source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Valindor)